# Updating Environment Vars from Session 0

Tags: c, windows, winapi, session, message

In Windows, to update Environment Variables I need to broadcast message WM_SETTINGCHANGE to all application, e.g.

```
SendMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, L"Environment");
```

But what with situation when service running in Session 0 needs to add environment variable template to registry and broadcast change to User Session? As far as I know SendMessage cannot be send across sessions. What can I do in such situation?

Comment: This won't work in more than one way.  Short from the session and window station problem, no program ever does anything to attempt to refresh its environment from the system environment registry keys when it gets that message.

Comment: Shell does and this is enough for me.